# The Fisher test warning

Tags: r

I am supposed to write a code to calculate the Fisher's exact test for the Iris data assuming the scientist sampled only 25% of the flowers in the original data. So I wrote this code:

```
obs.tab=matrix(c(47,11,1,3,36,32,0,3,17),nrow=3,
    dimnames=list(c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),
                    c("small","medium","large")))
new.obs.tab = obs.tab/4
fisher.test(new.obs.tab,alternative ="less")$p.value
```

**Warning in fisher.test(new.obs.tab, alternative = "less") : 'x' has been rounded to integer: Mean relative difference: 0.07317073**

But I keep getting this error. Can someone tell me what this error means and how to modify the code to avoid it?

Comment: You haven't sampled 1/4 of the flowers, you have divided the original counts by 4.  So you have fractional values in the table that Fishers exact test cannot deal with.

Comment: Then how do I sample 1/4 of the flowers?

Comment: Show all of your code. The iris data include 4 different measurements. Which one are you using? Use `sample()` to randomly select 1/4 of the original 150 observations.

Comment: (new.obs.tab=round(obs.tab*0.25)) would this work?

Comment: This works as long as we are not assuming the sample is random.

Comment: what exactly does this error message mean?

Comment: Fisher's test is designed for count data. When you divided your counts by four, you created decimal values which are not counts.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting the frequencies to 1/4 of the original values as @Demo12 suggests answers the OP's question as posed. It may be worth considering a slightly different question. Given a table of frequencies, can you explore the implications of different sample sizes by sub-sampling the original data?

```
obs.df <- as.data.frame.table(obs.tab) # Convert table to data frame
idx <- rep.int(1:9, times=obs.df$Freq) # Convert data frame to long data frame
obs.long <- obs.df[idx, 1:2]
names(obs.long) <- c("Species", "Size")
rownames(obs.long) <- NULL
str(obs.long)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Species: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Size   : Factor w/ 3 levels "small","medium",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

This converts the table into a data frame identifying the Species and Size for each of the 150 observations. Now we sample from that data frame:

```
obs.samp <- table(bs.long[sample.int(150, 38), ]) # Draw a sample of 150/4 observations
obs.samp
#             Size
# Species      small medium large
#   setosa        10      2     0
#   versicolor     4     11     0
#   virginica      0      8     3
fisher.test(obs.samp)
# 
#   Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  obs.samp
# p-value = 3.908e-05
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Each time this code is run, you get a different random sample of 38 observations.